# What is the difference in computational power between qubit and bit (transistor)?

Tags: experimental-realization, classical-computing, ibm-quantum-devices

If I use for example 5-qubit IBM-Q quantum computer and we accept the law of quantum parallelism ($n$ qubit = $2^n$ ordinary bits), so does it mean that computational power of this computer is equal to only $2^5 = 32$ bits (transistors)? For example in last Intel core processors — hundreds of millions transistors, so is it right that ordinary processors at this time faster than 5-qubit computer for millions of times?